# Windows Centralize all User Accounts and Data

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop

I am looking for a centralized way to manage user accounts and data.

Each of our employee should have the ability to log into any work station within the company using his account and also will see the data etc which is associated to it. So if he has 3 files in the Documents folder on Computer A, he will see the same files on Computer B as well if he logs in (but no one else sees them)

The problem I am facing is to identify the correct solution for this problem. I read installing a Windows Server and create accounts on there would be an option, but will this also ensure the data separation between indiviual accounts? Or would this just enable multiple users to log into the same computer?

A hint into the right solution is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Each user on Windows has his documents in the folder `C:\Users\USER-NAME\Documents`.

Only that user can access his documents.
But anyone logging in with an administrator account can access everything.